# Autofac WithMetadata not working

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac

This is what I've got:

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IService
{
}

public class Service : IService
{
}

public class ServiceUser
{
    public ServiceUser(IEnumerable<Lazy<IService, INamed>> services)
    {
        var cnt = services.Count();  // Always 0.
    }
}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => new Service())
    .As<IService>()
    .WithMetadata<INamed>(m => m.For(n => n.Name, "Test"));
builder.RegisterType<ServiceUser>();
var container = builder.Build();
var su = container.Resolve<ServiceUser>();
```

The collection of Lazy<IService, INamed> services in the ServiceUser ctor is always empty. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong? One thing I immediately don't understand is where the concrete implementation of INamed is coming from. I guess Autofac generates that internally?  Please help clear things up for me.

Comment: Hi - your code looks perfect, I'll give this a shot in the debugger; assuming you have latest Autofac on .NET 4? BTW, the metadata implementation comes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779644.aspx

Comment: Definitely on .Net 4. I'll have to double check the Autofac version. I'll do so tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I was running 2.3.x. Upgrading fixed the issue. BUT, it was a *real* pain in the ass to have to update my MVC2 site to MVC3 just to use the latest Autofac. I really think it should maintain MVC2 backwards compatibility.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Rather than upgrade your entire site I do have to point out that there are other overloads of `WithMetadata` that you could have used with much less impact ;) Still - new Autofac, new MVC, sounds like a win!

Comment: Only I'm running this on Linux and Mono's support for MVC3 hasn't been totally vetted. So it's maybe not the best situation for me to upgrade. And I tested the issue, and it was present, on both .Net and Mono, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest Autofac.